# How to deep copy entities in a relational database (rows in multiple tables) updating only PKs/FKs to preserve referential integrity?

Tags: oracle, algorithm, graph, deep-copy

I have (more than) one Oracle relational database that can be seen as a directed acyclic graph. Basically it has a "central" table representing the "subject" and many other tables connected with incoming/outgoing edges, depending on who is referencing who in terms of referential constraints, and this repeats to a custom depth (>1). Each table has its own surrogate primary key as a number(19,0) taken from a sequence.

This is a rough example, just to give an idea.

[image]

Red table is the "starting node".
Let's say I have a book with id 100, with *n* chapters, *m* authors etc...
I would like to duplicate book 100 (identical to the original except for PKs/FKs) by creating

- a new record with BOOK.ID = 101 preserving all the other columns
- *n* new records in CHAPTERS table identical to the ones referring to book 100, except for the foreign key that needs to reference to BOOK.ID = 101
- and so on

At this point the graph is not given by the tables alone but by their rows: nodes are the actual rows and I might have more rows for each table in my graph.

I've already written down a PL/SQL code to do the job, it basically perform a breadth-first visit analyzing nodes and edges, and then uses some "execute immediate *dinamically generated queries*" to create the twin graph.

Apart from the algorithm (that can be surely optimized) and the use of right PL/SQL semantics (I'm not a PL/SQL expert), I was wondering if such a problem has already been faced and maybe solved with some common function, or maybe Oracle itself provides some tool, or anything else.

I've gone through this algorithm for a while (I wanted it to be generic, so no table names are included in the code, they're passed as input to the procedure) but sometimes I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel in a not so elegant or performant way. Maybe there's some well known "literature" as per the *greatest-n-per-group* problem that I'm not aware of...

Is there a smarter way to solve this problem, other then writing a custom algorithm from scratch?

## Edit: algorithm pseudocode

```sql
/*
*    PHASE 1: initialization
*/

    //populate DC_TABLES with the list of tables to be copied (from DC_CONFIG), each one flagged with status "TODO"
    //populates DC_FKS with all the foreign keys existing between tables to be copied (from Oracle data dictionary) with status "TODO"
    //populates DC_NODES with the root node (provided as an input)
    //update DC_TABLES setting status "CANDIDATE" to those tables connected to root node table with an incoming/outgoing FK 

/*
*    PHASE 2: DAG traversing
*/

    while (any change happened){
        
        forEach(CURRENT_TABLE from DC_TABLES having status "CANDIDATE")
        {
            CURRENT_TABLE.status="DOING";
            
            forEach(INCOMING_FK from DC_FKS in status "TODO"){ //analyze fks from "other table" to CURRENT_TABLE
                insert into DC_NODES nodes of the "other table" (source table of incoming_fk);  //just the PK
                insert into DC_EDGES foreign_key_instances from "other table" to CURRENT_TABLE;
            }

            forEach(OUTGOING_FK from DC_FKS in status "TODO"){ //analyze fks from CURRENT_TABLE to "other table"
                insert into DC_NODES nodes of the "other table" (dest table of outgoing_fk);    //just the PK
                insert into DC_EDGES foreign_key_instances from CURRENT_TABLE to "other table"; 
            }
            
            CURRENT_TABLE.status="DONE";
            CURRENT_TABLE.adjacent_tables="CANDIDATE";
        }
    }

/*
*    PHASE 3: Query composing
*/

    while (any change happened){
        
        forEach(CURRENT_TABLE having no outgoing fks or, if any, towards already copied tables){
            
            pk_col = names of PK column;
            fk_cols = names of FK columns;
            other_cols = names of other unchanged columns;
            
            forEach(CURRENT_NODE = row of CURRENT_TABLE to be copied){
                pk_value = value of PK column;
                fk_values = values of FK columns;
                
                //compose and run following query
                INSERT INTO current_table(pk_col,fk_cols,other_cols)
                SELECT     pk_value,fk_values,other_cols
                FROM     current_table
                WHERE     pk_col = old_pk_value;
                
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a representation of phase 2 (breadth-first DAG traversing) to collect PKs and FKs info for each node:

[image]

This is a representation of phase 3 (query composing and execution) to insert nodes, and this must be done in a specific order not to break referential integrity

[image]

Comment: I see no general solution because it is neither a shallow copy nor a deep copy. You don't want to copy authors or nations but the rest should be copied. Unless the procedure would accept which tables to copy as parameter.

Comment: I want to copy ALL the tables. It is a deep copy indeed.

Comment: But why would you ever want to have a duplicated author or nation? I can somewhat understand it for books because you could have different releases (but even then why do it in the database and not in an application where you could change ISBN for example before saving?). Could this be an XY problem?

Comment: That's just an example to have something concrete in front of the eyes. My real-world example is much more complex and makes much more sense (it's about "digital paperwork", made of clustered data, a lifecycle...)

Comment: Does the graph have a **single** edge between nodes, or can it have multiple edges for each pair?

Comment: @TheImpaler single edge

Answer (score 1):

The approach that I've used for this is to migrate data from relational tables to structured data at the one database, and then migrate data from structured data to relational tables at the other.  Both sides of this are the bread and butter of what an ORM is supposed to do for you, and therefore I'd look for ways to use your ORM to handle it for you.

See https://rlskoeser.github.io/2016/03/31/migrating-data-between-databases-with-django/ for an example of someone doing this with Django.  And, for a bonus, they were migrating not just from one database to another, but from one database engine to another!  With data being moved in batches for better throughput!

When you are done developing this for yourself, I strongly recommend maintaining the tool.  One of the key uses is to take a problematic example from production and replicate it in a development environment where a developer can more easily debug it.

Comment: That's a clever strategy... I can see a little downside to this approach, though. Going with my "naive" algorithm I don't need to know anything about the database other than tablenames and sequences (for autogenerated PKs). Using an ORM would require some DB-specific code to be created and maintained (in case a new column is created/removed or else). But your idea has some undeniable advantages indeed.

Comment: @LuigiCortese We even have that covered, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb will automatically create your model from the database.